# Why am I not able to scrape just this particular P tag?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am using scrapy shell just to make sure my selectors for my spider are correct. I am able to get all other sections I need except this one p tag that contains the cross ref part numbers. I am scraping from this particular page [here](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537.html)

When I try `response.css('div.col-1-2-2' > div.rpr-help m-chm > div > p::text').extract()` it returns blank

When I try `response.css('div > p::text').extract()` the results have the section I am looking for plus a bunch of data I do not want.

I have a feeling this is going to be a super easy answer, but I have no idea what I am missing here

This is a snippet of the html section of the page I am trying to scrape, the last 'p' tag starting with Part Number

```
<div class="col-1-2-2">
        
        <div id="img-detail" style="text-align:center;">
            <div id="img-detail-main">
                <a id="ctl00_cphMain_imgenlarge" rel="nofollow" href="/detail-img.aspx?id=3094537&amp;i=" class="cboxElement"><img id="ctl00_cphMain_iMain" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_01_l.jpg" style="border-width:0px;outline:none;">
                    <div class="img-overlay" style="display:none;"><img src="/images/play.png" style="height:107px;"></div>
                    <div id="main-text-overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            
                    <div class="img-help">Click image to open expanded view</div>
                    <div id="img-detail-thumb">
                
                    <div class="a-button a-active">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl01_imgTh" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_01_tt.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl02_imgTh" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_02_tt.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl03_imgTh" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_03_tt.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl04_imgTh" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_04_tt.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl05_imgTh" src="https://cdn.appliancepartspros.com/images/product/cache/whirlpool-clutch-assembly-285785-ap3094537_05_tt.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl06_imgTh" class="diagram" data-dcmt="Clutch assembly AP3094537 is number 5 on this diagram. This is to give you an idea of the appearance and the location of the part. Your appliance model may be slightly different." src="https://483cda5f439700fab03b-6195bc77e724f6265ff507b1dc015ddb.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/0029384112_4.gif" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="a-button">
                        <img id="ctl00_cphMain_rImgTh_ctl07_imgTh" class="video" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/7RS1l6t8efc/hqdefault.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
                        
                            <div class="img-overlay"><img src="/images/play.png"></div>
                        
                    </div>
                
                    </div>
                
        </div>


        
        <div class="rpr-help m-chm">
            <div class="header">
                <h2 class="h6">Repair Help</h2>
            </div><!-- /end .header -->
            <div class="inner m-bsc">
                <ul>
                    
                    
                    <li><a href="#videol">Repair Video</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#qa1">Repair Q&amp;A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
                <div>
                <br>
                <span class="h4">Cross Reference Information</span><br>
                <p>Part Number 285785 (AP3094537) replaces  2670, 285331, 285380, 285422, 285540, 285761, 285785VP, 3350015, 3350114, 3350115, 3351342, 3351343, 387888, 388948, 388949, 3946794, 3946847, 3951311, 3951312, 62699, 63174, 63765, 64176, AH334641, EA334641, J27-662, LP326, PS334641.
                <br>
                </p>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works
`response.xpath('//div[@class="col-1-2-2"]//p/text()').extract_first()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also, `response.xpath('(//div[@class="rpr-help m-chm"]//p//text())[1]').get()`

Comment: Thanks Shivam but with td it only extracts first number even with .getall()

Comment: Correct me if am wrong but the part number is the one which is enclosed by parentheses. Do you want any other number?

Comment: I was looking for the entire text in the P tag, all numbers. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: No Problem, I didn't get the question. Please, check the modified answer and let me know if it works.